# Algorithm in IEEE journal

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran

Here is the [template](https://ieeecs-media.computer.org/assets/tar/ieeetran-final_sub.tar) I use for the following [journal](https://www.computer.org/csdl/journal/tk/write-for-us/15073?title=Author%20Information&periodical=IEEE%20Transactions%20on%20Knowledge%20%26%20Data%20Engineering). The algorithm is perfect in regular latex document as can be seen in: 
[image: figure].
I have problems with all the algorithm when inserting it to the template.

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}


\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm} 
            \caption{Esdfdfsy} 
            \label{alg:ALG1}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \textbf{INPUT:} dsgdasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaagadsgdas\\
                \textbf{OUTPUT:} Prediction of $W_{t_c}$ records    
            \end{flushleft}
            \begin{algorithmic}

            \ForAll {$i$=1 to $N$}
            \Comment{fdasdfn fdas}
            \State dfasdsf $afsddfs_i$  from $T_i$
            \EndFor

            \State Apply $HAT$ to  $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{F} W_{i}$ \Comment{IIIIII process -fdsdfsfsd}\\

            \If { $wr < htr$ }          \Comment{Nfsddfssdfasdf  }  
            \State $s = 0$
            \Else
            \State $ s = \floor {wr / htr}  $
            \EndIf
            \State xxx = 0
            \While {     $WYU_c \not=\O$ }
            \State c = c + 1
            \State Update $XXXXX$ with $W_{(dfsf2)-f}$



            $\parallel$   \Comment{in parallel}
            \\$Eadssad (W_{t_{c-1}})$ =  Predict ( dasda ($dasa8_{t_c-2,..,t_c-N-1}$ ) ) over $dsad_{t_c-1}$
            $\parallel$
            \\ $J48 (W_{t_{c-1}})$ = Predict ($J48_{t_{c-2}}$) over $W_{t_c-1}$     \Comment{This is done as part of the ensemble }



            \EndWhile   
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Add the packages `algpseudocode` and `algorithmicx` in your preamble ... The order could be: `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`
`\usepackage{algorithm}`
`\usepackage{algorithmicx}`. This will solve the errors

Comment: Also you can change the while content like `\While {     $WYU_c \not=$\O }` Because `\O` is not defined in math mode.

Comment: I get errors while adding the packages algpseudocode and algorithmicx

Comment: Check the code in my answer please ... You possibly are loading in an incorrect order or added `algorithm` package twice etc.

Comment: Please, make your document example minimal.In it you provide only a package related to your problem. btw, `subfigure` is obsolete package, replace it with `subfig` (which has different syntax) or even better with `subcaption`. from my answer on your previous question you should know that you can remove `amsmath˙package sine you use it supersede `mathtools`, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my comment in your code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}


\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm} 
            \caption{Esdfdfsy} 
            \label{alg:ALG1}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \textbf{INPUT:} dsgdasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaagadsgdas\\
                \textbf{OUTPUT:} Prediction of $W_{t_c}$ records    
            \end{flushleft}
            \begin{algorithmic}

            \ForAll {$i$=1 to $N$}
            \Comment{fdasdfn fdas}
            \State dfasdsf $afsddfs_i$  from $T_i$
            \EndFor

            \State Apply $HAT$ to  $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{F} W_{i}$ \Comment{IIIIII process -fdsdfsfsd}\\

            \If { $wr < htr$ }          \Comment{Nfsddfssdfasdf  }  
            \State $s = 0$
            \Else
            \State $ s = \floor {wr / htr}  $
            \EndIf
            \State xxx = 0
            \While {     $WYU_c \not=$\O }
            \State c = c + 1
            \State Update $XXXXX$ with $W_{(dfsf2)-f}$



            $\parallel$   \Comment{in parallel}
            \\$Eadssad (W_{t_{c-1}})$ =  Predict ( dasda ($dasa8_{t_c-2,..,t_c-N-1}$ ) ) over $dsad_{t_c-1}$
            $\parallel$
            \\ $J48 (W_{t_{c-1}})$ = Predict ($J48_{t_{c-2}}$) over $W_{t_c-1}$     \Comment{This is done as part of the ensemble }



            \EndWhile   
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @koleygr, I get an error for your code: Undefined control sequence. \ForAll

Comment: possibly you forgot to add `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` ... please be carefull with these three lines and their order as said in the comment too